# Charcter is Not able to Jump in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{ 
 CharacterController characterController;
[SerializeField] private float speed = 5.0f;

public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
public float gravity = 20.0f;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

private void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical) * (speed * Time.deltaTime));

        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {

            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("vertical"));
            moveDirection *= speed;

            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    
}
```

I was new in game development when I am making an game but I got the problem that the character is not able to jump and when I try to move the character it keeps floating on the air.

Comment: Can you share your characterController.isGrounded code?

Comment: Here in your code your moving your character twice using two different methods, the first was with Transform.Translate, and the second was with charController.Move is it an intended behaviour? I would suggest using the charController.Move, if you are still encountering the problem try adding a Debug.Log to debug your code to check if it even gets inside of the Jump section

Comment: @ErikOverflow the isGrounded is a member of the characterController component in unity

Answer (score 0):

This code here works for me

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                    rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight, 0);
                    //jumpheight is set at 14, and my gravity scale is at 4
            }
```

you will have to reference your 'rb' like:

`public Rigidbody2D rb;`
then drag your players rigidbody into the new Rb that shows up on the script.

rb.velocity adds a velocity of the original x velocity and sets the y velocity to 14, and z velocity = 0.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).